# Ubuntu 14.10 64 Bit, USB Install "Boot Error"

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded an Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit iso, then put it on my 8GB USB. I closed my laptop then plugged the USB in and opened the laptop, I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> to get the "Boot Menu", then I clicked "USB Flash Drive" (Something like that), then it said "Boot Error"

Comment: I did, I used http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ I used that thing to put the iso to my usb

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just copy the ISO to the USB drive, you have to create it using UnetBootIn or some other ISO to USB program.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the .iso file is not enough. You need to burn it like CD or DVD. You can make a live USB by using the following method:

- Download Ubuntu ISO image from http://releases.ubuntu.com
- Download Unetbootin from http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net
- Insert your USB, then launch Unetbootin. Check “Diskimage” and choose the Ubuntu ISO file. Your USB drive should be selected automatically.
- Click OK to start creating Live USB.
- You'll see "Installation complete, Reboot(Current)" once finished.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your processor is 64 or 32 bits. Then download the appropriate Ubuntu ISO file. After that, do not copy the ISO file into your USB key, that is useless. You rather need to create a bootable sick without necessarily using a third party software as shown on this [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

Also, when you boot from the BIOS, you need to pick the USB boot option as the first one on your boot menu.